# MongoDB create collection failure

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to
1. Create a database

```
use testdb switched to db testdb
```

2. Create collection

```
testdb.createCollection(testcollection)
```

I am getting following error:

```
2015-05-12T11:21:19.619-0700 E QUERY    ReferenceError: testdb is not defined
    at (shell):1:1
```

Comment: should be `db.createCollection("testcollection")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way is by using the [**`db.createCollection()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/#db.createCollection) method, your code fails because `testdb` is not a mongodb object in your call `testdb.createCollection(testcollection)`. Try the following:

```
> use testdb
switched to db testdb
> db.createCollection("testcollection")
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.getCollectionNames()
[ "system.indexes", "testcollection" ]
>
```